# Popup over child webview

Tags: ios, objective-c, cordova, uiwebview

I am doing cordova-ios hybrid application. Some places I need to display pdf files, so I wrote plugin to show pdf on child webview. Once pdf get loaded, I am placing child webview as an overlay to the existing webview. Everything working fine but some buttons are still visible on on the parent webview. When user tap on it, options popup is coming but it is below the child browser. I need the popover should come over the child webview itself. Any help/solution would be appreciated :) Thanks!

Comment: If you are talking about html buttons/menus, then there is nothing you can do, your child webview is over the cordova webview, the things that are below the child webview won't be visible. The only thing I can think of, is injecting the necessary html, css and javascript into the child webview to create the menus/buttons inside the child webview

Comment: Its not possible because I am loading PDF/Documents from URL. Anyway Thanks :)

Comment: then you'll need native buttons